# Как обрезать половину слова

Tags: javascript

помогите пожалуйста мне нужно обрезать половину строки в javascript, но я не знаю самого слова, что  мне делать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087416/split-string-in-half-by-word

Comment: что значит "но я не знаю самого слова"?

Answer (score 3):

```js
let str = 'Hello word!';
document.write(str.split('').splice(0,str.length/2).join(''));
```

Comment: а если одно слово а не два?

Comment: Тогда нужно учить `JavaScript`.

Comment: @Миша  тут строка ровно пополам поделена, а не на два слова, просто длины у них одинаковые получились со знаками препинания.